# Disabling Database Writes for a Dry Run

Tags: c#, multithreading, remoting

I have a Windows service which inherits from `MarshalByRefObject`.

While running, this service will occasionally receive a file then:

- Read data from database
- Do calculations
- Write result to database

I want to implement a function, let's call it `TestRun()`, that can be called remotely which will:

- Read data from database
- Do calculations
- Return result to the caller **without writing anything to the database**

For obvious reasons, I want `TestRun()` to use the same calculation code as the regular service, which is littered with `UpdateDatabase()` calls.

Here is a simplified version of what I currently have:

```
static bool commitChanges = true;

public CalcResult TestRun()
{
    try
    {
        commitChanges = false;
        return ProcessData();
    }
    finally
    {
        commitChanges = true;
    }
}

private CalcResult ProcessData()
{
    DataModel data = QueryData();

    //Note: DoCalculations() calls a bunch of other functions with complex
    //      objects many of which make multiple calls to UpdateDatabase().
    CalcResult result = DoCalculations(dataModel);

    return result;
}

private void UpdateDatabase(CalcResult result)
{
    if(commitChanges)
    {
        //Write data to database
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm pretty sure if someone calls `TestRun()` while the service is already processing data, it's possible that some of the real data might not get written to the database.

What is a better way to disable queries for a test run than using a boolean flag?

Comment: Remoting is a legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development. Distributed applications should now be developed using WCF or ASP.NET Web API. See the note at the top of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xws7132e.aspx for proof.

Comment: This isnt thread safe....

Comment: @AK_ Did you read the question? That's the entire point.

Comment: It's very relevant in two cases: 1) In case you thought that Remoting is a current technology and 2) In case a future reader thought that Remoting is a current technology.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry for my comment, but it seems I am the one who read too quickly. When I read "WCF" I was thinking "WPF", too many similar acronyms. That said, I am fully aware of Microsoft's recommendation for WCF over Remoting, but I don't see how that would fix the problem being discussed here.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it would solve this problem. It would have solved the problem of you using the wrong technology, but that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an optional argument to `ProcessData`.

```
public CalcResult TestRun()
{
    return ProcessData(writeToDatabase: false);
}

private CalcResult ProcessData(bool writeToDatabase = true)
{
    DataModel data = QueryData();

    CalcResult result = DoCalculations(dataModel);

    if (writeToDatabase) UpdateDatabase(result);

    return result;
}

private void UpdateDatabase(CalcResult result)
{
    //Write data to database
}
```

Comment: The provided example is over-simplified.. perhaps too over-simplified. In reality there are tens or hundreds of `UpdateDatabase()` calls buried deep within the `DoCalculations()` hierarchy. Passing a variable through to the 50+ functions would make parameter lists ugly as hell; I need a more central approach that is also thread-safe.

Comment: Edited example in OP to hopefully better illustrate this fact.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which makes use of [ThreadLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I wrote a simple client/server test app using .NET remoting to verify that remoting calls are executed on a new Thread and that using `ThreadLocal` works as expected; they are, and it does.

I replaced:

```
static bool commitChanges = true;
```

with

```
private static ThreadLocal<bool> _commitChanges = new ThreadLocal<bool>(() => true);
private static bool commitChanges
{
    get { return _commitChanges.Value; }
    set { _commitChanges.Value = value; }
}
```

Comment: Note: Normally I would capitalize field names, but I wanted to keep naming consistent with the original example.